# Entity Framework Core migrations error using UseInMemoryDatabase

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm trying to separate my Entity Framework and Identity to a different library but I can't do any migrations when I use `builder.UseInMemoryDatabase(connectionString);`.

I can do migrations when I change it to `builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);`, but I need to use `UseInMemoryDatabase`.

Here is the error when I try to add migration:

> Unable to resolve service for type Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.IMigrator'. This is often because no database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.`

Code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            //modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(ApplicationDbContext).Assembly);
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContextFactory()
        {
        }

        public ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();

            var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
            var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            builder.UseInMemoryDatabase(connectionString);

            return new ApplicationDbContext(builder.Options);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the reference

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="2.2.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

but the `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory;` is unused namespace.

Comment: why are you running migrations as part of using the inmemory provider?

Comment: because i dont want to deal with sqlserver during development.

Comment: theres localdb which is an option. in memory is a short term thing that doesn't have migrations.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The in-memory concept in meant to simulate your database in your memory (RAM). Migrations are used to generate/update your database schema to the connected database. The in-memory database doesn't need migrations. You can directly start your application and start using your DBContext without trying to add migrations.

As for your confusion with the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory` namespace, you have not written any code that uses the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory` namespace. Note that not every class under a NuGet package is under the  namespace. For convenience, the `UseInMemoryDatabase` extension function is created within the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` namespace. This way you don't have to add a using statement each time you change your db.

Comment: ohh, i just thought i need a different migration schema if i were to use inmemorydatabase